# How to add index number to object key?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I have an array of objects like this:

```
const data = [
  {name: 'Page A', count: 4000},
  {name: 'Page B', count: 3000},
  {name: 'Page C', count: 2000},
  ];
```

I need to add an index number to the count property so the list would look like this:

```
const wantedArray = [
  {name: 'Page A', count1: 4000},
  {name: 'Page B', count2: 3000},
  {name: 'Page C', count3: 2000},
  ];
```

I tried this but got this ts error: Operator '+' cannot be applied to types '{ name: any; count: any; }' and 'number'.ts(2365)

```
let wantedArray: any = []

data.map((object: any, index) => {
    wantedArray.push({
      name: object.name,
      count+index: start.count,
    });
  });
```

What is the best solution to achieve this? Thank you.

Comment: Please avoid using `.map` for simple iteration. Use `.forEach` or an actual loop for that.

Comment: Why do you need this?

Answer (score 0):

Use bracket notation - `[key]` for the dynamic key.

```js
const data = [{
    name: 'Page A',
    count: 4000
  },
  {
    name: 'Page B',
    count: 3000
  },
  {
    name: 'Page C',
    count: 2000
  },
];


const wantedArray = data.map((obj, index) => ({
  name: obj.name,
  [`count${index+1}`]: obj.count,
}));

console.log(wantedArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply assign wantedArray to map of the data array, also use `[]` to assign values with dynamic key.

```js
const data = [
  {name: 'Page A', count: 4000},
  {name: 'Page B', count: 3000},
  {name: 'Page C', count: 2000},
  ];

let wantedArray = data.map((obj, index) => {
    return {
      name: obj.name,
      [`count${index+1}`]: obj.count
    }
 });
 console.log(wantedArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `[variablename]` to write inside a variable name.

And since the index starts at `0`, we do `+ 1`.

```js
const data = [
  {name: 'Page A', count: 4000},
  {name: 'Page B', count: 3000},
  {name: 'Page C', count: 2000},
];

const result = data.map((n, i) => {
  return {
    name: n.name,
    [`count${i+1}`]: n.count,
  }
});

console.log(result);
```

Or if you want to push it into a new array.

```js
const data = [
  {name: 'Page A', count: 4000},
  {name: 'Page B', count: 3000},
  {name: 'Page C', count: 2000},
];

let wantedArray = [];

data.forEach((object, index) => {
  return wantedArray.push({
    name: object.name,
    [`count${index+1}`]: object.count,
  });
});

console.log(wantedArray);
```